# Save multiple arrays to a csv file with column names

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

As simple as it seems, I could not find any solution for my question online. Basically, I have two arrays `a` and `b` that I want to save to a csv file. It will be two columns. I want to add the column names as well. Below code I use to dump arrays to a csv.

```
from np import array, savetxt

a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])
savetxt('submission2.csv', zip(a,b), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
```

How would I add column names? I would like the csv file to look like

```
Name1 Name2
 1     5
 2     6
 3     7
 4     8
```

It is so strange that this option is not in the `savetxt` function. `header` option does do it because it just pastes a comment into the first cell. Thanks.

Edit: Arrays

Comment: The first row is where you would put column names; do you want row names instead? Can you give a sample of how you would want the file to look like?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid added details

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `header` option, like this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=',', header="A,B", comments="")
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
A,B
1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00
```

Comment: is there a way to add the column to an existing csv file? Also, how can I get rid of the e?

Comment: @duldi you can change the format with the `fmt` kwarg. The default is `%.18e` which includes the e. Try `%f` or `%g` depending on your needs

Comment: ```fmt='%i'``` for an output in integers

Answer (score 35):

You can do it with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)  package easily:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])

df = pd.DataFrame({"name1" : a, "name2" : b})
df.to_csv("submission2.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This works, but I would think the option below (from @Burhan) is going to be quicker and more memory efficient, since you don't have to create a copy of your entire matrix as a Pandas DF

Answer (score 2):

Note that `savetxt` (and `loadtxt`) also takes file handles.

Hence if you want a more advanced header you can do this:

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])
with open('submission2.csv','w') as f:
    f.write('# This is a very complex header\n')
    f.write('A,B\n')
    savetxt(f, zip(a,b), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
```

Or, as has already been noted, use the `header=str(...)` argument.

Comment: I think you meant np.array(list(zip(a,b)))

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
import np import array, savetxt

a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])
f = open("submission2.csv", "w")
f.write("{},{}\n".format("Name1", "Name2"))
for x in zip(a, b):
    f.write("{},{}\n".format(x[0], x[1]))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for saving multiple numpy 1D arrays as columns:

```
 import numpy as np
 data = []
 for i in single_np_arrays:
     data.append(i)
 data = np.array(data).T  #transpose the array to have proper columns
 np.savetxt('columns_from_np_arrays.csv',data,delimiter=',')
```